# IE script error with my jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter

I cannot seem to figure out I am getting the following error in IE 8 (only IE version I've tested so far).  The script runs fine in all (chrome, ff, safari) other browsers I've tested.  What am I doing wrong?

**Error:**

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 52
Char: 29
Code: 0
URI: http://www.ntierdesign.com/jquery/livetwitter/Scripts/jquery.liveTwitter.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/bloomsdayreg.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1251868075768&_=1251868075882

**Example:**

Hopefully I won't cap out my twitter api rate limit too fast, but you can view an example of the page here
http://ntierdesign.com/jquery/livetwitter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this error because the version of IE that you are using doesn't implements [Array/indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/indexOf), which has been introduced in [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6).

However you could add the indexOf method to the Array prototype if it doesn't exists, for compatibility.

This is the implementation that Firefox uses internally:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++) {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Check with IE [this example](http://jsbin.com/ogobe) of your page, having the compatibility function added, runs without problems...

Comment: Thanks CMS, I haven't done a lot of javascript dev, but I'm really surprised that I've never run into that before.

Comment: You're welcome @ntierdesign... welcome to the strange world of cross-browser scripting... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error points directly to line 52, char 29, which is the .indexOf method on array.

this method is *not* implemented on IE's javascript - hence the error.

luckily there are tons of workarounds on the web, eg. [link text](http://www.stellapower.net/content/javascript-support-and-arrayindexof-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that if you want to use a native jQuery approach, you can use the inArray function in the utilities class.
[jQuery inArray Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider the name, I've already released a similar plugin. :)

http://github.com/elektronaut/jquery.livetwitter/tree/master

Comment: Nice work elektronaut.  No worries, it's not really for public consumption.  I only made it a plugin, so I could learn more.